# Documenting name / email of author of Go file

Tags: go, documentation

How is the author of a go file documented?

The [Go Doc](https://go.dev/doc/comment) does not say a word about this. In Java there is a special `@author` tag where all contributors can be listed. Not acceptable is to refer to the code commits in the version control system. This is not contained with the code and would be lost if exported.

To clarify, I do NOT want to add author information for a complete project or package as metadata, like mentioned above it must be on file level.

Comment: @JimWright No, this is for a complete project, it must be possible to do this for individual files.

Comment: @k_o_ well you mentioned "at least package level". with doc.go file in a package you can do that, as stated in the post provided in the first comment.

Comment: @AminMal Well, the doc.go seems to be a fallback solution which I have to be forced to consider then, ideally a file based solution would have been the best. I will wait for a while, maybe some ideas are still coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go doesn't have this thing.
You can see the source repository from the import string though, also go.mod contains all the dependencies.
Adding a readme file on the repository is your best bet.